# Recursive feature elimination with SVM with python

Tags: python, svm, libsvm

I want to print all the features connected with rfecv.

```
# Create the RFE object and compute a cross-validated score.
svc = SVC(kernel="linear",C=5)
# The "accuracy" scoring is proportional to the number of correct classifications
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=svc, step=2, cv=StratifiedKFold(4),scoring='accuracy')
rfecv.fit(X, y)

print('Optimal number of features: {}'.format(rfecv.n_features_))
```

How should i retrieve the Optimal number of features from 'X'?

Answer (score 0):

Use following attribute:

> support_ : support_array of shape [n_features]
>
> ```
> The mask of selected features.
> ```

You can get names of selected features using:

```
datadf.columns[rfecv.support_]
```

For relative rank of each feature:

```
rfecv.ranking_
```

See documentation here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html